# Anyone recognise this app (and how to identify)?

Tags: windows, backup, icons

Started up my W10 PC and noticed a new icon on my Start Menu, under "Recently added". The thing is, I don't recognise or remember adding anything recently. It's a sort of turquoise cloud icon with a white up arrow and is labelled "Windows Back up". It would be easy to assume it's a genuine MS Windows feature, but the grammar makes me suspect otherwise. Does anyone know what this is?

I've tried to find out by using the context menu options - App Settings just takes me to general Windows app settings but I can't find this in the list. Rate and Review opens the Windows Store but only the homepage. Share also opens the Windows Store, but says the page can't be found. I tried browsing my Start Menu folders in Windows Explorer but don't see it there. Is there any other way I can identify it (without actually running it)? TIA for any suggestions.

Shortcut called "Windows Back up":

[image]

Comment: Is it in the Start Menu folder for all users?

Comment: What do you see if you right-click it and select Properties?

Comment: @squillman I couldn't see it in either Start Menu folder when I browsed them in Explorer, but maybe I just missed it!

Comment: @harrymc I don't get a Properties option if I right-click it in the Start Menu. I get App Settings, which takes me to a 'Windows Feature Experience Pack' settings page, which makes no mention of the app.

Comment: Which screen is "App Settings" ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a new app that Microsoft installed in September 2023 through Windows Update, [Windows Backup](https://www.windowscentral.com/software-apps/windows-11/windows-11-version-23h2-new-features-release-date-changelog-2023-update), "a cloud backup tool... which will make it easy to back up settings, files, and apps to your OneDrive storage." Though the citation refers to Windows 11 it has also been added to Windows 10. See also [this Pureinfotech article](https://pureinfotech.com/windows-11-23h2-new-features/).

[image: Windows Backup]

In the screenshot in your question, the icon is correct, but there **appears to be a space** between *Back* and *up* which does not belong there, as shown in my screenshot, above. Hopefully, this is just an example of atrocious kerning in the screen font, but if you're suspicious, run a virus scan.

Comment: `Windows Back up` is how it appears on my 2 Windows 10 machines

Comment: Also, I haven't (yet?) got it on any Windows 11 machine

Comment: @Bravo, thanks for that info. On the Windows 10, 22H2 v. 19045.3448, USA locale PC used for the screenshot, *Backup* has no space, whether in Start menu or in Search result. The executable is *WindowsBackupClient.exe*, Perhaps the differ ence in spell ing is due to locale, or if the app was acquired through Windows Insiders. Or it could be inept malware masquerading as a legit app. Or perhaps a virtual particle or dark matter inserted a space...

Comment: well, it appeared on 2 windows 10 machines when expected, and both have no space (en-AU locale) - the executable lives in `C:\Windows\SystemApps\MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy\WindowsBackupClient.exe` and has version `123.20100.0.0` - the executabe is English US

Comment: @Bravo, I don't understand... your first comment clearly shows a space between "back" and "up", and now you state "both have no space." Could you please explain those conflicting statements?

Comment: sorry, the "no" was a typo ... should've read "both have the space"

Comment: Thanks for your replies, everyone. Yes, there definitely seems to be a space between the words on my PC, and interestingly I've just noticed exactly the same thing turn up on my work laptop - again, appearing to have a space between 'Back' and 'up'. Both en-GB, so maybe that's something to do with it, but it still looks like a grammar howler in whichever flavour of English!